How to combine many m3u8 hls playlists into one using python
I have several videos of mp4 formats. I created HLS (playlists and segments) from them using this code
import ffmpeg

input_file_path = "D:/Projects/test2.mp4"
output_playlist = "'D:/Projects/playlist.m3u8"
segment_time = 5
file_name = "test"

ffmpeg.input(input_file_path).output(
    output_playlist,
    format='hls',
    hls_time=segment_time, 
    hls_list_size=0,  
    hls_playlist_type='vod',
    hls_segment_type='mpegts',
    hls_segment_filename=f'D:/Projects/{file_name}_%03d.ts', 
    force_key_frames=f'expr:gte(t,n_forced*{segment_time})'
).run()

Then I put segments to s3 storage and save m3u8 playlist structure for each video in database.
Now I need on some request combine some video that appropriate user's criteria as one full video and return it. I suppose that I could just combine one common playlist using the videos playlists but it failed. I used this code for this
from m3u8 import loads, 

video_one_m3u8 = """
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:10.166667,
test1_000.ts
#EXTINF:6.166667,
test1_001.ts
#EXTINF:6.433333,
test1_002.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
"""

video_two_m3u8 = """
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:8.000000,
test2_000.ts
#EXTINF:8.333333,
test2_001.ts
#EXTINF:5.533333,
test2_002.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
"""

playlist1 = loads(video_one_m3u8)
playlist2 = loads(video_two_m3u8)

combinedPlaylist = M3U8()
combinedPlaylist.segments.extend(playlist2.segments)
combinedPlaylist.segments.extend(playlist1.segments)

combinedPlaylist.version = playlist1.version
combinedPlaylist.target_duration = max(playlist1.target_duration, playlist2.target_duration)
combinedPlaylist.is_endlist = True

with open(r"D:\Projects\playlist_test.m3u8", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(combinedPlaylist.dumps())

The result of combined m3u8 playlist is below
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:10.166667,
test1_000.ts
#EXTINF:6.166667,
test1_001.ts
#EXTINF:6.433333,
test1_002.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
test2_000.ts
#EXTINF:8.333333,
test2_001.ts
#EXTINF:5.533333,
test2_002.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

When launch this playlist in VLS it works until the edge of another video then it crashes. The VLS log shows this errors
main error: Timestamp conversion failed for 5433334: no reference clock
main error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 5) for PID 17
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 5) for PID 0
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 5) for PID 4096
direct3d11 error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4

I trying to solve this problem of timestamps while preparing initial video playlists using ffmpeg.output argumets (start_at_zero=True and reset_timestamps) but it doesn't help.
Also I was trying to add tag EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY, it works but the video plays as separate (each starts from the beggining) not as common.
